# Issue to remove index.php? from URL with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with the htacces in my hosting, and the support does not respond.

I control my web from the index.php, I take the request from GET and by a switch the script include X file:

```
$parametros = $_GET['accion'];
$parametros = explode('/', $parametros);
$accion = $parametros[0];
```

Then, I remove the "index.php?accion=" with htaccess, this works fine in my localhost, but in the server it doesn't work and I don't know why... This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?accion=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webmail\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://consultoraley.com/$1 [P]
```

When you go to any url the server returns a 404 not found message...

I really would like to solve this problem, thanks you so much!

Comment: did you check `mod_rewrite` module on?

Comment: thanks for the reply! look, in the php info doesnt appear the "Loaded Modules" row, but if you search for "rewrite", you can found this:
url_rewriter.tags a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry

The php info:
http://consultoraley.com/phpinfo.php